# Speech to text for HINDI language in android

Tags: java, android

I tried for speech to text for Hindi language using below code.

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,"hin-IND");
```

But speech to text only taking as per the phone language setting.

Comment: Tts recognizes 3 letter codes, so use use "hin"

Comment: For your kind info it's not tts. i want for speech to text.I tried all those but still it is taking from phone default language i.e English.Can you help me more]

Comment: Have you tried hi-IN and EXTRA_LANGUAGE (not EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL?

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,"hin-IND");

to :

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,"hi-IN");

As per the Google Cloud VISION Api's Speech to Text Documentation. It Provides all the IETF language tag (as defined by BCP 47), for every languages.

Here you will find all the languages tags.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages